# Cannot build Flutter web application due to missing fonts

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error when I try to run my Flutter 3.3.9 web app in VS Code:

```
Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "lib/fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf"
```

I've added the following to pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
fonts:
- family: FontAwesomeBrands
  fonts:
    - asset: lib/fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf
      weight: 400
- family: FontAwesomeRegular
  fonts:
    - asset: lib/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf
      weight: 400
- family: FontAwesomeSolid
  fonts:
    - asset: lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
      weight: 900
```

Yet, I'm still getting the error. Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The font declaration in the pubspec must be under flutter.

As per the example given in the documentation: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts#2-declare-the-font-in-the-pubspec.

So in your case, moving your font declaration should fix the error:

```
flutter:
    fonts:
    - family: FontAwesomeBrands
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/fonts/fa-brands-400.ttf
          weight: 400
    - family: FontAwesomeRegular
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf
          weight: 400
    - family: FontAwesomeSolid
      fonts:
        - asset: lib/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
          weight: 900
```